# Turn a div into two columns that is pulling data using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am fairly new to PHP and am using an existing code from a previous developer. Currently I am returning cities all in one column as buttons as seen here: http://idr.maneuverup.net/inpatient-california/

I would like to return them in multiple columns.

This is the code that returns all of my cities for the specific state:

```
<?php

$segments = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));

$requestState = $segments[0] ? $segments[0] : null;

if (strpos($segments[0], 'inpatient-') == 0 && !$segments[1]) {
   $requestState = str_replace('inpatient-', '', $segments[0]);
   $dataOnly = true;
   include_once 'gen/gen.php';
   }
?>
```

It is a custom built generator that I am currently working with. I would like to return the cities in two columns if there are ten or more cities returned by the query. Any help would be appreciated!

This is how I am declaring the buttons:

```
<? foreach ($cities as $city): ?>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" href="/inpatient-<?= $state->url ?>/<?= $city->url ?>"><?= $city->name ?> (<?= $city->num_locations ?>)</a>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Maximum of two columns, even if there are more than 20? Should the cities be distributed evenly among the two columns, or 10 in the first column and the rest in the second column?

Comment: Good point, It would be nice to have more than two columns if there are more than 20 cities. I'm trying to make it so the user doesn't have to scroll so much to find their city and make it more user friendly. So possibly 20 cities = two columns, 30 cities = three columns, and 40+ cities = four columns. If this is possible

Comment: It doesn't have to be evenly distributed between the columns. @Don'tPanic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break your array of cities into groups using array_chunk.

```
$columns = array_chunk($cities, 10);
```

Then you can display the cities in each column pretty much the same way you currently are.

```
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    echo '<div class="column">';
    foreach ($column as $city): ?>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" href="/inpatient-<?= $state->url ?>/<?= $city->url ?>"><?= $city->name ?> (<?= $city->num_locations ?>)</a>
    <?php endforeach;
    echo '</div>';
}?>
```

You can use CSS (something like `.column { float: left; }`) to make your column divs display as columns.

Comment: Thank you! This has helped put me on the right path! I am going to have to figure out how to deal with States that have Large amounts of cities but this is a start! @Don't Panic